# How to regrid a 3D DataArray with 2D x/y and 1D time coordinates?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I want to regrid a data cube with dimensions `(t, y, x)` where t is 1d and `x/y` are 2d, onto another cube using `t_new/y_new/x_new` all 1d.

Problem is when defining a `DataArray` with 2d coordinates, both logical (`x` and `y`) and physical (`xc` and `yc`) coordinates must be defined. Then, when applying `DataArray.interp(x=x_new, y=y_new)`, `x_new/y_new` are treated as logical coordinates instead of physical coordinates!

So my question is: how do I regrid/interpolate this `DataArray` (defined below) using 1d physical coordinates, which should operate on `xc/yc` (2d) and not on `x/y`?

This is what I'm doing:

```py
import xarray as xr

da = xr.DataArray(cube, dims=['t', 'y', 'x'],
                  coords={'t': time,           
                          'xc': (['y', 'x'], X),  
                          'yc': (['y', 'x'], Y)})

da_interp = da.interp(x=x_new, y=y_new).interp(t=t_new)
```

Note that the `t_new` coordinate gets treated correctly as a physical coordinate... I suspect because it was defined as a 1d array.

In sum, `x_new` and `y_new` should be mapped onto `xc` and `yc` when using `DataArray.interp(x=x_new, y=y_new)`... If this interpolation should be handled in a different way, I haven't seen that mentioned anywhere!

Comment: Can you provide an example of `X`, `Y`, `time`, `cube` ,and `x_new`, `y_new`, and `t_new` which re-create your issue so we can better understand your question?